# Any php function to to drop decimal part if its zero

Tags: php, digits

javascript `Number` function is handy when dropping undesired zero if decimal part is zero e.g

```
Number(2.00)
```

> 2

Is there such function in php or any alternative

Comment: no , removing decimals if they don't make any sense , e.g `Number(1.20) => 1.20` but  `Number(1.00) => 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this works that way by default in PHP. If you use proper number type like `float` or `double`.

If you're using string then you need to map

```
$a = '2.00';
echo (float)$a; // 2
```

Example of using float

```
$a = 2.00;
echo $a; //2
```

or

```
2.00 + 0; //2
```

If you want to format the number to show decimal part `2.00` you need to use `number_format` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$a = 2.00
echo number_format($a, 2); // 2.00
```

Comment: Blatantly edited once you saw the correct answer .. Hope you win the competition :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `intval()` or any `roundoff` function

```
$_float = 1.9020441;
$_float = explode(".", $_float);
echo strlen($_float[1]);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding zero ... for example

```
echo "Result " . (2.00 + 0) . "\n";

Result 2
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Result 2`?

Comment: Yes i do :) ... thanks for the note - changed

Answer (score 0):

you can use `floatval()`

```
echo floatval('2.00'); //2
echo floatval('2.23'); //2.23
```

[See the documentation for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)